# The term 'update-database' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

Im using VS 2015 Community Update 3. When I try to recreate EF-driven database with command `update-database` in Package Manager Console, the error is displayed:

> The term 'update-database' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
>   name, or if a path was included,  verify that the path is correct and
>   try again.

I restarted VS a few times and reboot Windows OS, but no good results. Any help?
My packages.config file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Cors" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin" version="5.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Cors" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Did you try with update EntityFramework nuget ?

Comment: Yes, it worked:) Strange:)

Comment: Tyrone's answer worked for me; https://stackoverflow.com/a/46018504/1327316
Please check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes this error occurred because of EF nuget.

Please try to reinstall or update EntityFramework nuget package.

```
Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.1.3
```

Answer (score 19):

With EntityFrameworkCore I had the same problem. I found this:

Just install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` package from nuget:

> Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools -Version 3.1.1

You can also use this link to install the latest version: 
[Nuget package link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools/)

Copied from [Nasir Jafarzadeh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52566023/6276704)

Answer (score -1):

I solved by updateing Package Manager Console. My EF was updated.

I was not getting Update-Database in Package Manager Console. Then i restart several time. Also restart Windows.

Then I download new one from nuget and then it was solved.

Comment: what command did you use to update Package Manager Console?