# The EF Core tools version '3.1.2' is older than that of the runtime '3.1.7'. Update the tools for the latest features and bug fixes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

```
PM> update-database
Build started...
Build succeeded.
The EF Core tools version '3.1.2' is older than that of the runtime '3.1.7'. Update the tools for the latest features and bug fixes.
```

I tried a local update.
As different projects might use different versions on the same machine.

If I do this

```
$ dotnet tool update dotnet-ef
```

I get this error
Cannot find a manifest file.

This is my version number:

```
$ dotnet ef --version
Entity Framework Core .NET Command-line Tools
3.1.5
```

Answer (score 75):

UPDATE
This turned out to be an issue with a lot of facets. Main problem was Visual Studio:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/438312/vs-2019-preview2-after-saving-edmx-code-is-not-gen.html

---

Please try

```
dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef
```

and restart Visual Studio

Comment: After runnign this, I get this error - .dotnet/tools is int $PATH:
 The term 'Update-Database' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that 
the path is correct and try again

Comment: Please have a look at this question and see comment with 11 upvotes right below the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674983/the-term-update-database-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet/21256165    He says: Simply exit and restart VS (or unload/reload the project)

Comment: I saw that and applied the solution they sugested. Including rebooting my machine but the same issue. I have entityframework core, design,sqlserver 3.1.7. My points are too low to comment on that question to discuss my issue.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using? Several solutions in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40810258/the-term-update-database-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet-function   I guess a Nuget update to latest version of EntityFramework is the most likely one

Comment: Thanks. And what version of Nuget EntityFrameworkCore  are you using?

Comment: As I said, it is 3.1.7

Comment: visual studio: 16.6.3

Comment: Ok, then both tools and EntityFrameworkCore should be the lastest and aligned. I will need some time to investigate further. While I am doing that, can you try to create a brand new EF Core project and see if that is working on your computer?

Comment: Please try this in order to make sure all setting are present: dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef And make sure you have a dotnet-tools.json under .config folder. Should contain:   "tools": {
    "dotnet-ef": {
      "version": "3.1.7",
      "commands": [
        "dotnet-ef"
      ]
    }
  }

Comment: This is the result or running the command: Tool 'dotnet-ef' is already installed.  closed/open VS And the term is still not recognized. What should be in $PATH?

Comment: That is just an info message, and is ok. What about dotnet-tools.json file I wrote about?

Comment: I don't have a .config folder (i checked for hidden folders: ls -la). where should it be? I have a project folder with Foo.sln & src/web/Foo.csproj & test/Foo.csproj

Comment: Run this in folder where your .sln file is: dotnet new tool-manifest  then run: dotnet tool install --local dotnet-ef

Comment: Ran the commands successfully and got this:  but still update-database is not recognized
````{
  "version": 1,
  "isRoot": true,
  "tools": {
    "dotnet-ef": {
      "version": "3.1.7",
      "commands": [
        "dotnet-ef"
      ]
    }
  }
}````

Comment: The visual studio update-database is not recognized but CLI commadn works - $ dotnet ef database update
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Done.

Comment: Nice. Something wrong with VC settings then. You're not alone on this one: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/438312/vs-2019-preview2-after-saving-edmx-code-is-not-gen.html

Comment: Updated my answer with link to VS-issue. If you feel that will be to any help to others, feel free to upvote my answer (not accept it).

Answer (score 5):

It was still complaining and specifying the version worked for me:

dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef --version x.x.x

Comment: Thanks, this was the one that did the trick for me (from 7.0.8 to 7.0.13)!

Answer (score 4):

There should be no harm using the newer tool with older versions of EF. You'll get bug fixes and features to the *tool* that should all be backwards compatible. Unless you are using different *major* versions (2.x vs 3.x) I think in this instance that `--global` is the right way to install/update the tool.

Otherwise you need to have a `.config/dotnet-tools.json` file in your project (or a directory *above* it somewhere). This is the manifest file that the error says is missing. You can create a new one with `dotnet new tool-manifest` but then you'll have to edit it yourself:

```
{
    "version": "1",
    "isRoot": true,
    "tools": {
        "dotnet-ef": {
            "version": "3.1.7",
            "commands": ["dotnet-ef"],
        }
    }
}
```

Once you've done that you need to run `dotnet tool restore` to restore and install the tool locally. More info on the manifest file can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/local-tools-how-to-use). For `dotnet-ef` specifically, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#installing-the-tools).

I'm not certain, but *fairly* positive that if you attempt to install the tool locally it should create the manifest and add the necessary info if it doesn't already exist. You might just need to try running `dotnet tool install dotnet-ef` within the project directory (and *not* `update`).