# Asp.net Core EF in VS 2015

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I follow [ASP.NET Core - New Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db) to use EF in Asp.net Core under VS 2015. But got below error after installing the packages.

> Startup project 'src\CoreMVCWebAPI' is an ASP.NET Core or .NET Core
>   project for Visual Studio 2015. This version of the Entity Framework
>   Core Package Manager Console Tools doesn't support these types of
>   projects.

In the document, it says, it need VS 2017 RC, I am wondering whether it is available under VS 2015, or is there any workaround that I could use EF in Asp.net Core, or Ado.net to retrive Data from SQL DataBase.

```
PM> Add-Migration MyFirstMigration
Invalid object passed in, ':' or '}' expected. (339): {
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    //Dependence for MVC
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    //Dependence for EF
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore":"1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools":"1.1.0-preview4-final"
    //Dependence for EF with SQL, this is avalible under VS 2017 RC
    //"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    //Entity Framework commands to maintain the database
    //"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview4-final"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    //used for Razor pages which are compiled at runtime,and the compiler needs access to reference assemblies,
    //to make sure it compiles correctly
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Source Code:https://github.com/Edward-Zhou/DotNetCore

Comment: Which tools version do you use? There is currently a change happening with VS 2017 that changes the project format, so the newest tooling versions (newer than preview2) will not work with VS 2015.

Comment: Use this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro). This demonstrates how to create ASP.NET Core 1.0 MVC web applications using Entity Framework Core 1.0 and Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cant use `MSBuild` (Visual Studio 2017) packages in `CSproj` (Visual Studio 2015) project. If you will change `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` version from `1.1.0-msbuild3-final` to for example `1.1.0-preview4-final` it should work

Also comments were not allowed in project.json to comply strictly with JSON format. See this announcement github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/24 and linked issue for more information/discussion.

Comment: Thanks, but it did not work, after only replacing 1.1.0-msbuild3-final with 1.1.0-preview4-final, I got error "Invalid object passed in, ':' or '}' expected. (339)".

Comment: That error sound like `project.json` problem. Can you show that file?

Comment: I have added it to the original post. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `project.json` looking good. Do you use `appsettings.json` or other json files? can you post them here?

Comment: I have upload my source code to github, please help to check it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Change your `dependencies` section in `project.json` like in my answer

Comment: great, it works with removing all of the "//" in my project.json. It seems Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools could not valid comment "//".

Comment: It was no point at comments but you just forget about `,` after `"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory": "1.1.0"` (last before `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`)

Comment: Not exactly, I did not miss ",". Below would not work `    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory": "1.1.0",
    //Test,
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"`, removing "//Test," makes it work.

Comment: Good to know. `project.json` was always bugged so i hope new XML (MSBuild) will work perfect

Comment: Comments were not allowed in project.json to comply strictly with JSON format. See this announcement https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/24 and linked issue for more information/discussion.

Answer (score 0):

You need a reference to EntityFrameWorkCore.Tools.DotNet in the Tools Section as below

"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.0.0"

For more info, look at my answer here.

[The term "Add-Migration" is not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38173404/the-term-add-migration-is-not-recognized/43485111#43485111)

Answer (score 0):

You must install an earlier version of EF Core, due to compatibility of .NET Core 2.0 with Visual Studio 2015.

I selected EF Core 1.1.5 version and got the message: "Successfully installed 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 1.1.5'"

Greetings, Andres!