# I cannot create migrations in ASP.NET Core. What is the solution?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

Visual Studio 2019 Community. I want to create a table to create the migrations and connect with SQL Server 2014. But when I run

```
add-migrations AddMusicStoreToDb
```

I get an error:

> add-migrations: The term 'add-migrations' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>
> At line: 1 char: 1
>   + add-migrations AddMusicStoreToDb
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo: ObjectNotFound: (add-migrations: String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId: CommandNotFoundException
>
> ---

`appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "ConnectingStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=DESKTOP-NHG0GU1\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MusicStoreList  ;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
  },

  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

MusicStoreListContext.cs:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace MusicStoreRazor.UI.Models
{
    public class MusicStoreListContext:DbContext
    {
        public MusicStoreListContext(DbContextOptions<MusicStoreListContext> options):base(options)
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Music> Musics { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using MusicStoreRazor.UI.Models;

namespace MusicStoreRazor.UI
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<MusicStoreListContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check if it is a duplicate of this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38173404/the-term-add-migration-is-not-recognized

Answer (score 1):

You need to prefix the command with `dotnet ef`

1. `dotnet ef migrations add AddMusicStoreToDb`
2. `dotnet ef database update`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

Comment: I haven't tried Add-Migration InitialCreate dotnet not available, dotnet not available your commands don't work

Comment: Both Entity Framework Core and Entity Framework 6 are installed. The Entity Framework Core tools are running. Use 'EntityFramework6\Enable-Migrations' for Entity Framework 6.
Enable-Migrations is obsolete. Use Add-Migration to start using Migrations.

Comment: Isn't that for VSCode and not Visual Studio?  Not sure which to use for Community Edition, as I have Professional Edition.

Comment: You type that in the command window in Visual Studio. In VS Code, you would type that in the terminal window.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed these required NuGet packages to your solution to perform database related operations in asp.net core code first?

**1. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer:** Provide classes to connect with SQL Server for CRUD Operation to Entity Framework Core

**2. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools:** Help to work with database related activity like add migration, script migration, get DB context, update database, etc

If not then install these packages using the package manager console or NuGet package manager.

Comment: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer and
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools installed does not show a problem with them.

Comment: Both Entity Framework Core and Entity Framework 6 are installed. The Entity Framework Core tools are running. Use 'EntityFramework6\Enable-Migrations' for Entity Framework 6.
Enable-Migrations is obsolete. Use Add-Migration to start using Migrations.

Answer (score 0):

I removed Entity Framework 6 and got a solution thanks